# Why does this program behave like `tail -f`

Tags: c, file, eof, fgetc

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c = EOF;
    FILE *fp = fopen("./temp.txt", "r");
    assert(fp!=NULL);
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (EOF != c) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*temp.txt* is a slowly increasing log file, so this program can read the EOF. After it first encounters EOF, I thought it should stop getting new added data of *temp.txt*, while it just acts like `tail -f temp.txt` and continues printing new lines of the file.

Yes, I know there is an infinite loop. The problem is that I thought,
when *fgetc* first encounters EOF, it should do some recording in the struct *fp*,
and the next callings of *fgetc* should check this and return EOF immediately.
Why it continues to read the data on the disks, didn't it reach the end-of-file?
Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: better to write: `while ((c = fgetc(fp)) !=  EFO){ putchar(c);} `

Comment: You're apparently linking your program against Glibc. Had you linked it against uClibc, it would have crashed on first call to fgetc after EOF. Reading from a FILE after EOF is unspecified.

Comment: Be aware that the proper way of knowing that your are at the end of the file is to use the `feof` function as describe in the man page.

Comment: Many implementations do as you expect.  However, not all do.  The behavior of `fgetc` after it has returned `EOF` for a stream is unspecified.

Answer (score 2):

Quick answer is, there is no `break` that exits the `while` loop.

When it reads `EOF`, it loops back around and holds on `c = fgetc(fp);`.

If you need it to stop reading when it hits the EOF you can add an `else`:

```
while (1) {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (EOF != c) {
        putchar(c);
    } else {
        // reached the EOF
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't telling it to leave the while loop when finding an EOF though, you are only saying if you do find a EOF don't do anything with it.  You would need to put a conditional break from the loop or have a condition until which the while loop will continue.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c = EOF;
    FILE *fp = fopen("./temp.txt", "r");
    assert(fp!=NULL);
    while (1) { // here
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (EOF != c) {
            putchar(c);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It's because you have an infinite loop which can't be stopped (except with some signals). This program will read `temp.txt` for the eternity.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int c = EOF;
    FILE *fp = fopen("./temp.txt", "r");
    assert(fp!=NULL);
    while (1) {
        c = fgetc(fp);
        if (EOF != c) {
            putchar(c);
        }
        else
          break; //this will fix your problem of infinite loop even finding EOF
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO it would be nicer looking when you do

```
int c = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
{
    putchar(c);
}
```